# how can i import data from a Json file with difference format?

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

How can i add such this to ui-grid? I have a .Json with below format :

```
0:["date","numberOfTransaction", "price"]
1:["20170207", "3029223", "5294194476028"]
2:["20170208", "2176469", "1479374036275"]
3:["20170209", "2902111", "6971208095034"]
4:["all", "8107803", "13744776607337"]
```

Comment: That is not valid json...show actual sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should init `ui-grid` option manually. i.e you should init `columnDefs` and `data` array of `ui-grid`.

**Like to this.**

```
  angular.forEach($scope.myData,function(data,j){
    angular.forEach(data,function(d,i){
      if(j ==  0)
          $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({field:d});
     else if(i == 0){
        var date = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[0];
        var numberOfTransaction = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[1];
        var price = $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[2];
    $scope.gridOptions.data.push({date:data[0],numberOfTransaction:data[1],price:data[2]});
  }  
  }  
 })
})
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qwfPVBfci4qbMEbwdNvM?p=preview)

Comment: if i have a column header with space . 
for example "number of transaction"
What changes are needed?

Comment: You do not need to change anything.Try test it in demo.

Comment: if i change var "numberOfTransaction" to "number of transaction" in demo
making the syntax error

Comment: why you change `var numberOfTransaction` to `var number Of Transaction`. its wrong.

Comment: the displayName of header must be "number of transaction"

Comment: what i see something that you want to. please see demo.

Comment: can you help me to this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158461/angularjs-how-to-export-ui-grid-data-to-excel-with-custom-html

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON is an object you need to access it by the property name.

```
 <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
     {{arr['0']}}
 </div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.arr = {0:["date","numberOfTransaction", "price"],
1:["20170207", "3029223", "5294194476028"],
2:["20170208", "2176469", "1479374036275"],
3:["20170209", "2902111", "6971208095034"],
4:["all", "8107803", "13744776607337"]}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 {{arr['0']}}
</div>
```

Comment: thank you 
can you describe this to ui-grid in plnkr?